# Sorting columns on multi-level index in pandas dataframe and removing blank row in the csv write

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, multi-index

This is a simple code that creates a two level dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=dates)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'E' : ["foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"]})
df2=pd.concat(dict(L0 = df, L1 = df1),axis=1)
```

df2 output:

```
                   L0                                          \
  2013-01-01 00:00:00 2013-01-02 00:00:00 2013-01-03 00:00:00   
0            0.530496           -1.536075           -0.592824   
1            0.614626            0.146761            1.799287   
2           -0.398504           -0.863021           -0.208724   
3            0.901720            0.717144            1.504012   
4           -0.570248           -0.967722           -0.478540   
5            2.225644            2.452121           -0.131774   

                         L1  
  2013-01-04 00:00:00     E  
0            1.293738  foo1  
1            1.469431  foo2  
2           -2.084461  foo3  
3           -0.199157  foo4  
4           -1.627641  foo5  
5           -1.970185  foo6
```

I have these three questions. Kindly help:

1) How can I reorder the columns such that the dates are in descending order?
2) How can I show only the date (not the time stamp) in the column header?
3) If you write df2 to csv, it creates a blank row. I read some QA and it indicates a bug with multi-level output. Is that been fixed? If not, what's the best way to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can attack the problem during the construction of `df2`, the
problem can be solved by sorting the columns of `df` and then turning the column
labels into strings:

```
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.format()
```

Using the current version of pandas, 0.21.0 (dev),

```
df2.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
```

creates a CSV with no blank row. If you try it with the latest stable version, 0.20.3, I think you'll get the same result (see below).

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=dates)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'E' : ["foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"]})

df = df.sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.format()

df2 = pd.concat(dict(L0=df, L1=df1),axis=1)
df2.to_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
```

creates `/tmp/test.csv` with the content

```
,L0,L0,L0,L0,L1
,2013-01-04,2013-01-03,2013-01-02,2013-01-01,E
0,0.02140012949846106,0.26277798576234707,0.3417048534674754,-0.2415864990096712,foo1
1,1.5529608360704856,0.04473119120484416,0.2563552549068564,-0.7234609815350183,foo2
2,0.3197702495146119,-0.4796536804964018,-1.0049744963838612,0.039249748655535384,foo3
3,-1.5129389373140296,-0.2528463527601262,-0.22930219559242235,-0.6661663277403631,foo4
4,0.03756426242171489,0.20880577998533037,1.0229358239647364,0.6539470866256701,foo5
5,-1.8477638391042324,-0.8315712350681457,-0.0743680147471108,0.8503850287138673,foo6
```

---

By the way, you might also want to consider this format, which seems a bit more compact:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), columns=dates)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'E' : ["foo1","foo2","foo3","foo4","foo5","foo6"]})

df = df.T
df.columns = df1['E']
print(df)
```

yields

```
E               foo1      foo2      foo3      foo4      foo5      foo6
2013-01-01  0.166074  0.398726 -0.410202  0.397486 -0.811873  0.462652
2013-01-02  0.406810 -0.313234  0.062569 -0.140924 -1.087162  1.600549
2013-01-03 -0.573118  1.331461 -0.115200 -1.934654 -1.427441 -0.889541
2013-01-04 -0.919885 -1.197192 -0.476039  1.186531  1.013803  0.400977
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu. This is a sample code and it works when I sort on df. But in my main code, I tried doing that and it will revert to original. Is there any way you could look at that and help? Also, how did format() remove the decimals in the df2. I tried reading about it but could not make sense.

Comment: Regarding the sorting that reverts to the original: put in a print statement to show you the state of the sorted DataFrame -- perhaps something like `print(df.head())`. Put it immediately after `df = df.sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1)`. Run the program. If it gives the correct sorted output, then advance the `print` statement a bit and check again. Repeated runs and the bisection technique (if the print is good, advance the print statement some more, if it is bad, back up half way...) will help you isolate exactly where the DataFrame is "reverting" to the original.

Comment: Since `df.columns` is a `DatetimeIndex`, its [format method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.format.html) returns a string. When the hour/minutes/seconds part is all zero, the string representation is shortened to YYYY-MM-DD format. By assigning strings to `df.columns` you can control how the column labels look in the CSV.